# Access html elements from page loaded with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with a div tag that I load different views into using jQuery .load()

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="load"></div>
</div>
```

When I load different views like the following, I can't access any of the elements from settings.html

```
$("#settings").click(function(){
    $("#load").load("main/settings.html");

    //not working
    $("#test1").click(function(){
       alert('hello');
    });
});
```

According to the second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) post:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call...

So I moved my `.click()` code to the page that was being loaded (settings.html in this case) and I can access the elements from settings.html. Or I can do the suggested similar code posted

```
$("#settings").click(function(){
    $("#load").load("main/settings.html", function(){
        $("#test1").click(function(){
           alert('hello');
        });

    });
});

//or
$("#settings").click(function(){
    $("#load").load("main/settings.html");

    $(document).on("click","#test1",function(event){
           alert('hello');
    });
});
```

But I'd like to know how to bind all the elements assuming I don't know which ones ahead of time. In the above examples I know I need to bind `#test1` id. But if I have a file like `play.js` where I'm changing different things on a loaded page, the methods listed above will require that I separate my code from `play.js` and put each piece in a function tied to the load event. I have lots of `.load()` events and wanted to keep my js like `.click()` etc in a separate file.

How do I bind *all* elements that are loaded without specifying them ahead of time? Or how do I tell jQuery to perform something like:

```
$("#settings").click(function(){
    $("#load").load("main/settings.html", function(){

        // pseudo code
        (function(){
           bind all elements from main/settings.html to DOM
        });

    });
});
```

So the scripts listed after it like this can access thoese elements.

```
<script src="../js/play.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: yes, it was in my original post. I've updated my post to try and improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are good solutions, however I would like to explain the actual *reason* this is occurring: `load` is an **asynchronous** function, meaning that instead of doing some work and returning when it is done, it schedules the work to be done and then returns immediately.

In this case, calling `load` means that *eventually* the content of `main/settings.html` will be obtained and placed in `#load`, however not by the time the lines of code immediately after it have run. Thus, your inability to select the not-yet-created elements.

To manage this style of programming, such functions often accept a `callback` as an argument, which is another function (provided by you, the user) which will be called by the API later when the operation has finished. In this instance, it's the second argument to `load`. Within this function, you can act on the result of the action.

Comment: Thanks. Jquery.load has an optional 2nd and 3rd params.  3rd is callback function: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Bind the content from the loaded page in the callback function of the first load.

```
$("#settings").click(function(){
    $("#load").load("main/settings.html", function(){
        $("#test1").click(function(){
           alert('hello');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I've updated my post to try and improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I would do:

In your HTML page, load in some `<script>`s like this:

```
function loadSettings() {
  $('#test1').click(function() {
    alert('Hello, world!');
  });
  // other event handlers...
}
```

You can make as many of these as you want.

Then:

```
$("#settings").click(function(){
    $("#load").load("main/settings.html", loadSettings);
});
```

This will load the `settings.html` page into the view, then call `loadSettings()`, which will set up your event handlers.